# Obfuscating problem when import jar file in project

Tags: java, java-me, obfuscation, proguard, j2mepolish

Hello I am creating a j2me polish project which jar size is very high as i am using 
j2me polish so i need to obfuscate the jar files

everything is work perfect but now i need to include one external jar file in my project
so as i am doing obfuscating using Proguard it is creating classes like a.class, b.class

so when my code reach to line where i use that external jar file giving me following error

No Class Def Found Error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErro

MypackageName.MyClassname

**For more clarification**

i am using eclips, compiling files using ant
then copy those compiled file in wtk scr, build in wtk
and after that using proguard doing obfuscating.

how to solve this problem??

Comment: add ext. jar in your project then build it and then obfuscate it

Comment: @org.life.java where will i find ext.jar???

Comment: yes i am doing this but this is giving class not found error

Comment: as obfuscating will change class name may be this is creating problem, is there some solution to come out of this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use / understand the [keep option](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions) of Proguard ?